# Spring Data Rest different data for same object depending on uri /files <-> files/1

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have problem with Spring-DATA-REST. I allready posted in the spring [forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?131789-Spring-Data-Rest-with-HSQL-in-memory-old-data-after-server-restart) but got no answer. Maybe here someone can help?

I have a test application set up with Spring-DATA-REST and all my domain objects get exposed by spring data rest.

Now: If I access my files repository under the uri /files/ I get a list of files I just created.

But: If I then access one of the files with the direct uri /files/{id}, for example /files/1
I get data from a file I entered long ago. I can't explain where this data comes from...

I just checked the JpaRepository. That is ok and I get the same data from a file retrieved with:

JpaRepository.findAll().get(0) as from
jpaRepository.findOne(JpaRepository.getAll().get(0).getId())

Is there some cache in spring data rest, that could still have the old data?

I am really desperate. Anyone has an idea on how to get my new data with spring data rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using HTTP as a transfer layer. If yes then you should look at HTTP cache headers in response. The result may be cached somewhere between. 
You may use:

```
curl -vvl uri/files/{id}
```

to see all response's headers.

Comment: Thanks ragnor! Your tip solved my problem! I am using jQuery.ajax() in Chrome and the cache was turned on